# Best practice for delaying program execution in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, handler, delay, postdelayed

I am making a quiz app for Android.

The user has 30 seconds to answer as many questions as they can.

I create a small gap in execution time between questions so the user can see if they got the question right:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {  
   public void run()  { displayNextQuestion(); }
    } , 1000);
```

At the end of the 30 seconds, the user is supposed to be redirected to a results screen. However, if the 30 seconds expires during that wait time, then the user is brought to the results screen for a moment, only to be redirected back to the next question. How can I disable that moment of wait time once the 30 seconds has elapsed?

Should be a simple answer, I just don't know how to work with threads/execution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your runnable and the handler to instance variables and call `myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable)` to discard the pending action.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a boolean to check if the results should be displayed, and then do something like 
    if(!resultsDisplayed){
        displayNextQuestion();
    }